# Remove All Character before a String and the String itself

Tags: php

I have image paths like that

```
com_jshopping/files/img_products/965cc2355d06eacf09958a79af552885.jpg
```

I want only `965cc2355d06eacf09958a79af552885.jpg` That is the image file name

I have tried

```
strstr($product->image,'img_products/')
```

But it outputs this `img_products/965cc2355d06eacf09958a79af552885.jpg`

I now I can use `str_replace()` here but

**Is there any other single function to achieve this?**

Comment: You could use `explode();`

Comment: Or you could use split("//", string) I prefer explode() though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHPs built-in function [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$fileName = pathinfo($product->image, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
```

Comment: I tried pathinfo() just now and it removed .JPG from the image names

Comment: You've to use `PATHINFO_BASENAME`. I wrote `PATHINFO_FILENAME` but that's wrong. I corrected it in the sample code above.

Comment: Corrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrect